# UIPageViewController Application - Populate with a pdf

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.2, uipageviewcontroller

i would like to populate this application but with a pdf instead of a string. how can i do ? i guess it is in the function - (void)createContentPages ... thanks a lot for the help.

that is the sample code used :

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

i changed the createContentPages, but it does shit, normal i guess, it is showing only the path of the image ( i tried with images, seems easier... ) :

```
- (void) createContentPages
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSArray *filelist;
    int count;

    int j;
    j = 0;
    NSMutableArray *pageStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/img", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]] error:NULL];
    count = [filelist count];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/img/Diapositive", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
        NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        NSString *concatinatedString = [path stringByAppendingString:intString];

        NSString *final = [concatinatedString stringByAppendingString:@".png"];


        [pageStrings addObject: final]; 
    }
   pageContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pageStrings];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the sample code you are citing, the base view is a UIWebView, which interprets the content as HTML. Just passing in a file path will not work. If you want the content, then it has to be wrapped in an appropriate HTML page.